# cakephp welcomepage showing error

Tags: php, cakephp, ubuntu

i am using `ubuntu 13.10` with xampp installed and running successfully.its path is 
`opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/www`.
i have downloaded `cakephp 2.4.6` and have extracted the tar.gz file to my web folder like
`/opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/www/cakephp`

now when i hit

`localhost/xampp/www/cakephp` its showing

`Warning: _cake_core_ cache was unable to write 'cake_dev_en-us' to File cache in /opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/www/first_app/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php on line 325`

`Warning: /opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/www/first_app/app/tmp/cache/persistent/ is not writable in /opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/www/first_app/lib/Cake/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php on line 384`

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'CacheException' with message 'Cache engine _cake_core_ is not properly configured.' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/www/first_app/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php:181 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/www/first_app/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php(151): Cache::_buildEngine('_cake_core_') #1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/www/first_app/app/Config/core.php(373): Cache::config('_cake_core_', Array) #2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/www/first_app/lib/Cake/Core/Configure.php(72): include('/opt/lampp/htdo...') #3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/www/first_app/lib/Cake/bootstrap.php(175): Configure::bootstrap(true) #4 /opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/www/first_app/app/webroot/index.php(90): include('/opt/lampp/htdo...') #5 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/www/first_app/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php on line 181`

may be some config changes should bring success,plz suggest

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please create app/tmp/cache directory with permissions 777.